# How to install mod_wsgi from lfd in 2015

Tags: mod-wsgi, python-wheel

How can I install mod_wsgi from lfd website as it has wheel extension.Whenever I am searching how to install mod_wsgi on wamp the resources tell me to install binary from this site and then keep the mod_wsgi.so file in my wamp directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the lfd page is a link to:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/master/win32/README.rst

You may want to read that.

The official mod_wsgi download area has binaries as .so files as explained in that link.

You can still use the whl versions when you work out how to install them, but the .so option does still exist.

Comment: I am not able to find the official mod_wsgi download area.I tried installing whl files but it tells there is no file name like that.

Comment: That document I linked to provides the link to it. It is given as https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases Ensure you read that document well so you know what binary to use.

Answer (score 0):

The WHL files from LFD (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) DO contain the pre-built WSGI module, but for obscure reasons it is called `mod_wsgi.pyd`. You can find it in `c:/python27/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/` (or whatever your Python installation or virtual environment path is).

Just rename it to `mod_wsgi.so` and copy it to the `modules` directory if Apache.

To get some initial help with setting up the Apache configuration, you may run

```
c:/python27/Scripts\mod_wsgi-express.exe module-config
```

More information about `mod_wsgi` on Windows and compatibility can be found here: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/master/win32/README.rst

Comment: Unless they changed away from their own build system, gohkle versions do not install mod_wsgi-express as far as I know. You only get mod_wsgi-express if you install it yourself using ``pip install mod_wsgi``. That link you provide to ``win32/README.rst`` in the mod_wsgi repository is obsolete and should not be used. See instead https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks. It seems that they do come with `mod_wsgi-express` now. The tricky part is that the module has a `.pyd` extension, which got me confused. Also I just realized that a simple `pip install mod_wsgi` will *of course* give me the module built with the correct compiler. Stupid me.

Comment: The ``.pyd`` extension doesn't matter, use the name as is in the ``LoadModule`` line and still works. Better still run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` as you note and it should output exactly what you should use, including a ``LoadFile`` line to make sure the correct Python DLL is used.