# How to install mod_wsgi on Windows+XAMPP in 2017

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

Im a trying (hard) to set up environment for Django app on Windows with XAMPP.

**What I have:**

- Windows 7 64bit
- Apache/2.4.25 (Win32)
- Python 3.6.1 `platform.architecture() = ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')`
- Cygwin 2.9.0(0.318/5/3)
- `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` pointing to `apache` dir in XAMPP installation

**What I did already:**

Tried to install with `pip install mod_wsgi` but it didn't work because `apxs` could not be found. So I've installed `httpd-devel` in Cygwin. Now it rises `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` error with massive output that I can't understand.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145068/842480), I've downloaded WHL file, exctracted PYD file but when I want to run Apache I get syntax error on `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.pyd`: `Cannot load modules/mod_wsgi.pyd into server: The specified module could not be found.`. I've tried 3 versions of WHL.

I'm new to Python/Django and WSGI and I'm already done ;-)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? You use mod_wsgi for deployment, you don't need it for development. Django is not PHP.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I like to have working vhosts without running additional commands and custom servers. I thought it should be easy... ;-)

Comment: Well, really you're making things hard for yourself. Django is rarely deployed on Windows, and even less rarely in Apache on Windows, so tooling is not as well developed as other platforms. You could try mod_wsgi-express which is supposed to be an easy installer. Or, run the whole thing under WSL (ie Bash on Ubuntu in Windows) rather than cygwin. But really, you're missing the flexibility that the dev server gives you by doing any of this.

Comment: You should not attempt to use ``pip install mod_wsgi`` under Cygwin, that environment is not supported. Use normal Window CMD prompt or Powershell and a normal Windows distribution of Apache such as that from apachelounge.com. Once installed use ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` to generate what you should add to the Apache configuration.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thanks. I have normal Apache distribution (XAMPP, but with updated Apache downloaded from official site's mirror, probably ApacheLounge). But Python is from Cygwin, I will try with standard installation. Additionally, I have upgraded Apache to 64bit. I'll try more with this.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton sadly I have to get rid of this. I have conflicts with requirements - WSGI needs standalone Python (not Cygwin's), but then I can't install Ansible because of compilers (it works with Cygwin's GCC). The other day I was trying to set up whole VS environment but after installing and uninstalling couple of times I couldn't get it to work. Whatever I did there was always some issues with missing headers or something. I don't want to deal with that again.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was creating a virtualenv using python3.6.2 (32 bits) and trying to install mod_wsgi on a vs2015_x86 command prompt, after set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIT and doing `pip install mod_wsgi` i'd get a bunch of unresolved errors.

Then I thought maybe it was required a 64bits version of python so I installed python3.6.2 (64 bits), created a virtualenv and opened a vs2015 x64 command prompt and the installation was smooth, ie:

```
(py362_64) D:\sources\personal\python\framework\engine\tests\test>set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9

(py362_64) D:\sources\personal\python\framework\engine\tests\test>pip install mod_wsgi                               
Collecting mod_wsgi                                                                                                  
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.5.18.tar.gz                                                                                
Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi                                                                     
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mod-wsgi ... done                                                                 
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\KneDa\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\75\86\b4\6e5bf5e1cea623c0578dc5d0424a32014f33cd3
bfde193d987                                                                                                          
Successfully built mod-wsgi                                                                                          
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi                                                                              
Successfully installed mod-wsgi-4.5.18
```

One thing you need to be careful about is how you set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR, using `/` instead `\` and not enclosing on double quotes.

EDIT:

Also tried to install mod_wsgi on a python3.6.2 (64bits) on a normal cmd prompt (no visual studio compiler available) without setting MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR and the wheel has been installed succesfully, ie:

```
(foo) C:\whatever>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
Successfully installed mod-wsgi-4.5.18
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to use standalone Python in CMD (not Cygwin's) but I got `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`. Tried to install Build Tools, but further errors occured (e.g. missing `cl.exe`). I've fought with it once for a long time because I wanted to install `ansible` and now I remember why I ended up with Cygwin's Python - it can use Cygwin's GCC and I was able to install `ansible`. I don't want experiment with VS again. I think I'll skip WSGI and use Python's server for development or maybe I'll finally switch to Unix ;-)

Comment: Mmmm, that's strange, as you can see I had that EDIT comment 2 days ago, maybe the wheel was being cache? I don't get it, if that was the case I should have seen the corresponding message :/ . In any case, I usually have a really great experience using vs' build tools... when i need to use a python unix packages i prefer to avoid these pseudo tools like cygwin (bad experience playing with python) and try to switch to virtualbox or real unix. Anyway, about the missing cl.exe, try to follow what i've suggested in my answer and open a "visual studio command prompt" so all env vars are set ok.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp was 64bit hence i used this 64bit python and set the root directory to C:/xampp/apache then installed mod_wsgi.

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/python-3.7.5-amd64.exe